# How to find duplicates and its indexes in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
l=['a','b','c','c','a','d']
```

The output should return all the duplicate elements and their indices in the list

Output:

```
out = {a:['0','4'],c:['2','3']}
```

I have tried

```
def nextDuplicates(c):
    dupl_c = dict()
    sorted_ind_c = sorted(range(len(c)), key=lambda x: c[x])
    for i in xrange(len(c) - 1):
        if c[sorted_ind_c[i]] == c[sorted_ind_c[i+1]]:
            dupl_c[ sorted_ind_c[i] ] = sorted_ind_c[i+1]
    return dupl_c
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l=['a','b','c','c','a','d']

result = {}

for element in l:
    if element not in result:
         indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == element]

         if len(indexes) > 1:
              result[element] = indexes

print(result)
```

Iterate through list and check if element already exista in dictionary. If it doesn't then get all the indexes for that element and append the element in dictionary.

Comment: I edited my answer. He could also add one more condition.

Answer (score 1):

A `dict` comprehension coupled with a `list` comprehension would work (even for more than 2 occurences) :

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "d"]
out = {el: [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == el] for el in l if l.count(el) > 1}
```

I saw in your expected output that indexes are strings. I don't understand why, but if you really want them as strings, replace `i for i, x` with `str(i) for i, x`.

[More on list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l=['a','b','c','c','a','d']
o = {}
for i in range(len(l)):
    if (l[i] in o):
        o[l[i]].append(i)
    else:
        o[l[i]] = [i]
print({key:val for key, val in o.items() if len(val) > 1})
```

Comment: returns positions of every element in the list

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.defaultdict` + a `set` iteration for a faster lookup for counts greater than 1:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ['a','b','c','c','a','d']

result = defaultdict(list)

for x in set(l):
    if l.count(x) > 1:
        result[x].extend([i for i, y in enumerate(l) if y == x])

print(result)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [0, 4], 'c': [2, 3]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this dict comprehension

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "d"]
out = {ele: [str(i) for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == ele] for ele in set(l) if l.count(ele) > 1}

# Output : {'c': ['2', '3'], 'a': ['0', '4']}
```

Rather than iterating over the list itself using the set will give a performance improvement especially if there are many duplicates.

In your expected output you wanted a list of `str` as the value. If you need int, you can use `i` instead of `str(i)`